# Select nth element inside nth element with XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to select second input in second row?

```
<div class="row">
  <whatever>
    <input/>
  </whatever>
  <whatever>
    <input/>
  </whatever>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <whatever>
    <input/>
  </whatever>
  <whatever>
    <input/> <!-- select this -->
  </whatever>
</div>
```

I tried `(//div[@class='row'])[2](//input)[2]` but it doesn't work.

I don't want `(//div[@class='row'])[2]/whatever[2]/input` because "whatever" is unknown amount of nested nodes i.e. it might be something like this:

```
<whatever1>
  <whatever2>
    <whatever3>
      <input/>
    </whatever3>
  </whatever2>
</whatever1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below xpath :

```
//div[@class='row'][2]/descendant::input[2]
```

or

```
((//div[@class='row'])[2]/descendant::input)[2]
```

**Explanation :**

input is `descendant` not direct `child` so you **can not** do

```
(//div[@class='row'])[2](//input)[2]
```

Comment: First example works with added parentheses (//div[@class='row'])[2]/descendant::input[2] Second one works as is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you were almost there here the fixed version of your first try :

```
((//div[@class='row'])[2]//input)[2]
```

`(//div[@class='row'])[2]//input` Matches all the inputs. All you need to select the second match.